# How can I do an update in Class::DBI without selecting a record first?

Tags: perl, class-dbi

To do an insert with Class::DBI, you can simply do:

```
my $object = Object::DB->insert({ a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, ...});
```

But there is no such thing for update. The best I could come up with is selecting the record first then updating it:

```
my $object = Object::DB->retrieve($id);
my $object->set( a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, ...};
$object->update;
```

This is not efficient since I have to do a SELECT first, and then an UPDATE instead of just one UPDATE.

Is there a better way to do this with Class::DBI? I don't want to do 42 $object->a(1), $object->b(2), etc., $object->update;

Comment: DBIx::Class makes this easy.  You should really consider moving away from CDBI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, Class::DBI does not have a good way to do this,  As you've noted, its `update()` method is meant to be called on an object that has been previously loaded from the database.

You may be able to convince Class::DBI to do what you want, however, with something like this:

```
# Make new "empty" object
my $o = My::CDBI::Object->new;

# Set the primary key column and discard the change
$o->set(your_pk_column => 123);
$o->discard_changes;

# Set your other columns
$o->set(a => 'foo', b => 'bar');

# Do the update
$o->update;
```

If this feature is important to you and you're not already too far into your project, you will definitely have better luck with one of the newer Perl ORMs such as [Rose::DB::Object](http://www.perlfoundation.org/perl5/index.cgi?rose_db_object) or [DBIx::Class](http://www.perlfoundation.org/perl5/index.cgi?dbix_class).  DBIx::Class even includes [a Class::DBI compatibility layer](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/CDBICompat.pm).

Answer (score 4):

One way that I've found to do this is to override the default iterator class for your objects.  This allows you to have a collection of individual objects with an update method on the collection.  Class::DBI provides an method for this:

```
__PACKAGE__->iterator_class('MyClass::CDBI::Iterator');
```

This allows you to then make an `update` method in the iterator class that can save all of the objects in the collection.  As such your code may look something like this:

```
my $collection = Object::DB->search_where({id => {'>=', 0}});
foreach my $obj ($collection->next()) {
  $obj->a('bob');
  $obj->b('tom');
}
$collection->update();
```

Which makes for some pretty well self-documented code.  If you go this route, I'd also suggest putting the `is_changed` method into use as the update() occurs.  It will help you save time by not updating unchanged rows.